# What's a good sound proofing material to fill an old aperture?

Tags: insulation, sound-proofing

Our bedroom has a disused aperture that looks like it was once for an extractor fan. Both ends are covered with a simple plastic grille.

We have serious a noise problem because of this vent. Short of filling it in with concrete, what would be an effective and easily available material to quickly and easily fill the hole in the wall?

Comment: Are there other active vent openings in hte room, such as an openable window? If not, this opening may be needed for air exchange and may be required by local building code.

Comment: yes, openable window. Also a couple of much smaller air vents / air bricks. I considered ventilation, which is why I don't want to concrete it. Was looking for something non-permanent. (I've actually stuffed it with the innards if an old pillow for now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rigid Foam Insulation](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Project-Panels-FOAMULAR-1-in-x-2-ft-x-2-ft-R-5-Insulation-Sheathing-PP1/203553730) Cut to fit the gap, use as many layers as needed, cover with the grille. If you determine that you will never need the hole again, take off the grille and finish the wall with a drywall patch or (if the wall is made of some other material), paint the foam directly (many types can be painted) or (lazy way out) hang a picture over it.